# Solving $(x-y) u_x + (x+y) u_y = \alpha u$ with initial conditions $u(x,0) = x^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the following problem

> Use the method to solve the problem
> $$
> (x-y) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+(x+y) \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\alpha u,
> $$
> where $\alpha$ is a constant, with initial condition $u(x, 0)=x^2, x \geqslant 0$.

I attempted this as follows. First I looked for characteristics satisfying
$$
x' = x-y ,\quad y' = x+y, \quad z'=\alpha z,
$$
where $'$ denotes derivative with respect to the parameterization variable $s$.

Assuming $x$ and $y$ are independent, I solved these to get
$$
\ln (x-y) = s+A, \quad \ln(x+y) = s+B, \quad \ln z = \alpha s+C
$$
where $A,B,C$ are constants. It follows that, by substitution,
$$
B-A= \ln (\frac{x+y}{x-y}) \quad z = T (x-y) 
$$
where $T$ is a constant. Because of that we can write $T$ as a function of $B-A$ giving a characteristic on our surface solution to be
$$
u = z = g(\ln \frac{x+y}{x-y}) (x-y)
$$
for some function $g$. Taking the union of all characteristics gives that the solution should be of the type
$$
u(x,y) = G(\ln \frac{x+y}{x-y}) (x-y)
$$
for some function $G$. Applying the initial condition I get that
$$
x = G(\ln 1),
$$
which is none sense.

I think that the issue is that there is some potential canceling out, however, I am not sure how to proceed. I tried using continuity of $u$ and arguing something of the lines
$$
x+ \delta = G(\ln \frac{x+\epsilon}{x-\epsilon}) (x-\epsilon)
$$
which still doesn't work.

This is all in the context of an applied course so the method of characteristics hasn't been analytically, however, I would still like to know the answer to two questions

- Was a mistake already made?
- How do I proceed?

If anybody could help me with that I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you put your solution into the PDE to check ? It seems that $u(x,y) = G(\ln \frac{x+y}{x-y}) (x-y)$ is not correct. Moreover where is gone the coefficient $\alpha$ which is in the PDE ?

Comment: The $\alpha$ is absored by the general constant I think. I am aware that the solution doesn't work but I can't understand why. I think maybe the issue is that I treated $x$ and $y$ as independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x-y) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+(x+y) \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\alpha u$$
Sorry I am not sure to follow your reasoning. So I prefer the method below :

Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{x-y}=\frac{dy}{x+y}=\frac{du}{\alpha u}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x-y}=\frac{dy}{x+y}$ :
$$\frac12 \ln(x^2+y^2)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{xdx+ydy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{du}{\alpha u}$ because :

$\frac{dx}{x-y}=\frac{dy}{x+y}=\frac{xdx+ydy}{x(x-y)+y(x+y)}=\frac{xdx+ydy}{x^2+y^2}$
$$(x^2+y^2)^{-\alpha /2}u=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ leads to the explicit form :
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)^{\alpha /2}F\left(\frac12 \ln(x^2+y^2)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.

The condition $u(x,0)=x^2$ determines without ambiguity the function $F$. That's for you.

Note :

$\frac{dx}{x-y}=\frac{dy}{x+y}=\frac{xdx+ydy}{x^2+y^2}$ is simply the application of a well-known property of the fractions :

If $\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}$ then : $$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{c_1A+c_2C}{c_1B+c_2D}$$ with arbitrary parameters $c_1$ and $c_2$ (not both nuls).

In the present case we have : $A=dx \:;\: B=x-y \:;\: C=dy \:;\: D=x+y \:;\: c_1=x \:;\: c_2=y$. Nothing mysterious nor complicated !

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Could you elaborate where does the equality $\frac{d y}{x+y}=\frac{x d x+y d y}{x(x-y)+y(x+y)}$ come from? On another note, I think the issue with my attempt is that I assumed $x$ and $y$ to be independent which your answer clearly shows they are not.

Comment: I added the explanation at the end of my answer. Of course $x$ and $y$ are not independant on each characteristic curve.

Comment: I think I understand now, thank you.  This is the first time I am seeing this property of fractions and moreover I think I would have found dealing with the first characteristic equation quite hard. This question is from an exam so I would assume that that specific year the students had seen something similar. Regardless, great answer!

Comment: In polar coordinates $(x=\rho \cos(\theta)\:,\: y=\rho \sin(\theta)\:)$ the PDE is : $\rho u_\rho+u_\theta=\alpha u$ and the solution is : $u(\rho,\theta)=\rho^\alpha F(\ln(\rho)-\theta)$.